# Is there a way to install ubuntu-live.iso onto a virtual filesystem that is mounted as a loopback device?

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount, filesystem

Creating a virtual filesystem (6GB)

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=my_fs bs=1024 count=6000000
```

Assigning the file as a block device

```
 losetup /dev/loop0 my_fs
```

Formatting the filesystem

```
mkfs -t ext3 -m 1 -v /dev/loop0
```

How can I install ubuntu on the loopback device using ubuntu-14.04-live.iso without virtalbox or qemu?

Comment: You don't. You **can** mount the iso itself. But, why do you think you want to do this? What do you actually want to do with your file?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I want to create a modified  OS  in my usb flash drive